# How to store all rows of a DataFrame to a local value (e.g. concurrent queue)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to iterate the Row's I got from executing a structured query using Spark SQL (pyspark). The code looks roughly like this:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Sessions")\
    .config(...) \
    .getOrCreate()

stuff = spark.read.format("parquet").options(mergeSchema=False).load(location)

result_set = spark.sql("""sql without udfs or anything too funky""")
result_set.foreach(lambda t: queue.put(t))
```

The `queue` is a local variable - a simple concurrent queue.

When the code reaches this line, I get the following error:

> pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: AttributeError:
>   'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '**code**'

Calling `collect` prior to the iteration works, but I wonder what the idiomatic way to perform such a traversal is? Why does the above code not work?

Comment: `pickle.PicklingError` means that you are trying to populate wrong datatypes than the one defined in schema

Comment: can you update the question with what `queue` is ? `result_set` is a dataframe and by doing `result_set.foreach(lambda t: queue.put(t))` you are trying to change the values of the dataframe with fixed schema and thats the main reason you are getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to queue data on the nodes and then use it locally - you need to use [accumulators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/python/pyspark.accumulators-module.html). Otherwise everything that is pushed to queue in `foreach` will not change anything locally.

You can read about shared variables (accumulators and broadcasts) [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#shared-variables).

Comment: Thanks, Of course! The queue is defined on the driver, there I was thinking each executor has a copy of it as well. I misunderstood the execution module

Answer (score 1):

You're calling DataFrame [`foreach`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreach) which will serialize and distribute your lambda to run on each partition on the executors. So if you truly want to push the rows to a queue then you need to initialize the queue in the lambda. [`foreachPartition`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreachPartition) might be more appropriate in this case so you initialize the queue client once per partition vs for every row. Or if you know the data size is small you could just call `collect` and queue the results on the driver.